# How can I use Task Scheduler from WinPE?

Tags: windows-pe

I need to run an exe at midnight each day.
Problem is that Task Scheduler doesn't exist on WinPE.

What can I do?

Comment: Can you use some alternatives instead, like [CRONw](http://cronw.sourceforge.net/) for example?